# Attempted import error: '@mui/utils/useControlled' does not contain a default export (imported as 'useControlled')

Tags: material-ui

Issue started after I start using `@mui/x-date-pickers`. I tried to verify if mixed some wrong versions, but it all looks correct.

```
$ npm ls --depth 5 | grep "@mui\|@finapi"
├─┬ @finapi-internal/finapi-design-system@0.190.0
│ ├── @mui/icons-material@5.11.16 deduped
│ ├── @mui/material@5.12.3 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/system@5.12.3
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/private-theming@5.12.3
│ │ │ ├── @mui/utils@5.12.3 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/styled-engine@5.12.3
│ │ ├── @mui/types@7.2.4 deduped
│ │ ├── @mui/utils@5.12.3 deduped
│ ├── @mui/x-data-grid@6.3.0 deduped
│ ├── @mui/x-date-pickers@6.3.0 deduped
├── @finapi/web-form@2.24.0
├─┬ @mui/icons-material@5.11.16
│ ├── @mui/material@5.12.3 deduped
├─┬ @mui/material@5.12.3
│ ├─┬ @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.128
│ │ ├── @mui/types@7.2.4 deduped
│ │ ├── @mui/utils@5.12.3 deduped
│ ├── @mui/core-downloads-tracker@5.12.3
│ ├── @mui/system@5.12.3 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/types@7.2.4
│ ├─┬ @mui/utils@5.12.3
├─┬ @mui/x-data-grid@6.3.0
│ ├── @mui/material@5.12.3 deduped
│ ├── @mui/system@5.12.3 deduped
│ ├── @mui/utils@5.12.3 deduped
├─┬ @mui/x-date-pickers@6.3.0
│ ├── @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.128 deduped
│ ├── @mui/material@5.12.3 deduped
│ ├── @mui/system@5.12.3 deduped
│ ├── @mui/utils@5.12.3 deduped
```

Edit: Updated `@mui/x-data-grid` and got rid of `@mui/lab`. Issue still persists.